# Need help with some Oracle SQL Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the question posed by a professor: Find the minimum and maximum length of movies playing in each city.

And here is how I have my tables structured:

```
CREATE TABLE Theatres (
Name varchar2(50) not null,
City varchar2(50) not null,
State varchar2(50) not null,
Zip number not null,
Phone varchar2(50) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Name)
);

CREATE TABLE Movies (
Title varchar2(100) not null,
Rating NUMBER not null,
Length NUMBER not null,
ReleaseDate date not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Title),
CHECK (Rating BETWEEN 0 AND 10),
CHECK (Length > 0),
CHECK (ReleaseDate > to_date('1/January/1900', 'DD/MONTH/YYYY'))
);

CREATE TABLE ShownAt (
TheatreName varchar2(50) not null,
MovieTitle varchar2(100) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (TheatreName, MovieTitle),
FOREIGN KEY (TheatreName) REFERENCES Theatres(Name),
FOREIGN KEY (MovieTitle) REFERENCES Movies(Title)
);
```

I've tried a few different queries, but keep getting issues.  Here is what I have:

```
SELECT MIN(Movies.Length), MAX(Movies.Length), Theatres.Name
 FROM Theatres, Movies, ShownAt 
WHERE ShownAt.TheatreName = Theatres.Name AND 
ShownAt.MovieTitle = Movies.Title AND 
Theatres.City IN (SELECT UNIQUE City FROM Theatres);
```

Anybody see anything wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You may want to explain what your query means, but you will either need ORDER BY ASC or ORDER BY DESC or MIN(), MAX() functions in your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close I think. Just missing `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
     MIN(Movies.Length) AS Shortest, 
     MAX(Movies.Length) AS Longest, 
     Theatres.City 
FROM Theatres
JOIN ShownAt ON ShownAt.TheatreName = Theatres.Name
JOIN Movies ON ShownAt.MovieTitle = Movies.Title
GROUP BY Theatres.City
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would do the trick:

```
SELECT T.City, MIN(M.Length) AS MinLength, MAX(M.Length) AS MaxLength
  FROM Movies   AS M
  JOIN ShownAt  AS S ON S.MovieTitle  = M.Title
  JOIN Theatres AS T ON S.TheatreName = T.Name
 GROUP BY T.City
```